# merging 2 queries into one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

here are my queires these are almost identical, till the last part

```
SELECT Offers.ID
FROM Offers, Products
WHERE Offers.IDProduct = Products.ID
AND Offers.fromDate <= GETDATE()
AND GETDATE() <= Offers.toDate
AND Offers.active = 1
AND Offers.IDHost = 1


AND Offers.ID IN
        (SELECT idobject FROM Multilingual
            WHERE Multilingual.IDLanguage = 2   
            AND Multilingual.IDObjecttype = 30
            AND Multilingual.active = 1)
```

second query is

```
SELECT Offers.ID
FROM Offers, Products
WHERE Offers.IDProduct = Products.ID
AND Offers.fromDate <= GETDATE()
AND GETDATE() <= Offers.toDate
AND Offers.active = 1
AND Offers.IDHost = 1       

AND Products.partnerObject = 0
```

If first query has no results then the second query will be executed.
Is there a way to to do this in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with multilingualobjects (objectid)
as
(
        SELECT distinct idobject FROM Multilingual
            WHERE Multilingual.IDLanguage = 2   
            AND Multilingual.IDObjecttype = 30
            AND Multilingual.active = 1
)

SELECT Offers.ID
FROM Offers o
inner join Products p
ON o.IDProduct = p.ID
left outer join multilingualobjects mo
on o.ID = mo.objectid
where o.fromDate <= GETDATE()
AND GETDATE() <= o.toDate
AND o.active = 1
AND o.IDHost = 1
and (mo.objectid is not null OR p.partnerobject = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

use or logic

```
and offers.idhost = 1
and 
(offers.id in (that subquery)
or
Products.partnerObject = 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try an OR clause?

Since the SELECT, FROM AND WHERE clauses are the same try an OR Clause in parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.ID
FROM Offers o JOIN Products p ON o.IDProduct = p.ID
WHERE o.fromDate <= GETDATE()
  AND GETDATE() <= o.toDate
  AND o.active = 1
  AND o.IDHost = 1       
  AND (p.partnerObject = 0 OR o.ID IN(
                                      SELECT idobject
                                      FROM Multilingual m
                                      WHERE m.IDLanguage = 2   
                                        AND m.IDObjecttype = 30
                                        AND m.active = 1
                                      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Offers.ID
FROM Offers, Products
WHERE Offers.IDProduct = Products.ID
AND Offers.fromDate <= GETDATE()
AND GETDATE() <= Offers.toDate
AND Offers.active = 1
AND Offers.IDHost = 1
AND 
(   
    Offers.ID IN
        (SELECT idobject FROM Multilingual
            WHERE Multilingual.IDLanguage = 2   
            AND Multilingual.IDObjecttype = 30
            AND Multilingual.active = 1)
    or 
    (
       (SELECT idobject FROM Multilingual
            WHERE Multilingual.IDLanguage = 2   
            AND Multilingual.IDObjecttype = 30
            AND Multilingual.active = 1) = 0 
       and
       Products.partnerObject = 0
    )
)
```